# Is there an inline operator that only does something if the value is true?

Tags: javascript, operators

I've found myself writing a lot of code similar to this:

```
$('.selector').addClass(condition ? 'class' : '');
```

I know this may be silly and whiny, but I was just curious if there was a way to do that without the false condition in Javascript. I've looked around and haven't really found any operator that can do that, but I could be (and hope I am) wrong.

I'm not necessarily looking to optimize my code, this is just curiosity :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript's `&&` operator [short-circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You'll see something like this used commonly in a number of scripts and libraries:

```
condition && $('.selector').addClass('class');
```

Or as mgibsonbr's comment states, you can simply `&&` within the method itself:

```
$('.selector').addClass(condition && 'class');
```

It's much less intuitive, though, as it's not a commonly-known fact that `a && b` results in `b` in JavaScript when both values are truthy, and not `true` unlike in other languages.

Comment: ohhh very cute! i was hoping for something though that i could put directly inline so i could maintain chaining. however this is a pretty cool idea :)

Comment: @Jason just use `condition && 'class'`, I don't think it will have any negative effects (or any effects at all) if you pass `false` to `addClass`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I would have predicted that result either.

Answer (score 3):

```
!condition || func();  // launch func only if condition holds
```

If `condition` is false, then `!condition` is true. As the first operand of `||` is true, the whole expression is true. The `func()` gets short-circuited and is not called.

If `condition` is true, `!condition` is false, so `func()` must be called in order to evaluate the disjunction.

Comment: nice. this is the corollary to BoltClock's answer I believe. awesome!

Comment: The main difference is that this will always return a "truthy" value, while BoltClock's can return `false` as well.

Comment: @Jason Yes, basically, I just typed it slower :) Well, in this example, you launch function if condition holds and do nothing if it doesn't. In your case, however, you want to return string if condition holds and... return nothing if doesn't? Does that mean the operator we're looking for (or inventing) should return undefined in the false case?

Comment: the functionality i was looking for was just do something if the condition was true and nothing if false. in my example, i just want to add a class if some condition is true, but i want to do it inline without breaking my chain and having to traverse the DOM again. microoptimization, i know, but if this trick becomes second nature, i don't have to worry about optimizing later :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own jQuery monadic operation. Though it should be used very sparingly (to reduce cluttering the $.* namespace), this is nevertheless the most elegant way to do so if you do this a lot.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.addClassIf = function() {  
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1);
        var condition = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, -1)[0];

        return condition ? this.addClass.apply(this,args) : this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo:

```
> $('body')
[<body class=​"question-page">​…​</body>​]

> $('body').addClassIf('test1', true)
[<body class=​"question-page test1">​…​</body>​]

> $('body').addClassIf('test2', false)
[<body class=​"question-page test1">​…​</body>​]

> $('body').addClassIf('test3', true)
[<body class=​"question-page test1 test3">​…​</body>​]
```